# Find conditional probability of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I need to find conditional probability to count mutual information. 
Random variable `X` has uniform distribution on set `{0, 1, 2}`. Variable `Z` has Bernoulli distribution with parameter `p=1/10`. `Y = X # Z, where # is "sum mod 3"`. I don't undestand the way how to count conditional probabilities.

Comment: What do you mean by "alternative distribution"?

Comment: @Math1000 Sorry, Bernoulli distribution.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Z$ independent?

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$Y = 
\begin{cases}
0,& (X,Z)=(0,0) \text{ or } (X,Z)=(2,1)\\
1,& (X,Z)=(0,1) \text{ or } (X,Z)=(1,0)\\
2,& (X,Z)=(1,1) \text{ or } (X,Z)=(2,0).
\end{cases}
 $$
So you can compute the distribution of $Y$ using the joint distribution of $Z$. For example if $X$ and $Z$ are independent then
$$\mathbb P(Y=0) = \mathbb P(X=0)\mathbb P(Z=0) +\mathbb P(X=2)\mathbb P(Z=1). $$

If you wanted to compute e.g. $\mathbb P(Y=0|Z=0)$, then using the definition of conditional probability
$$\mathbb P(Y=0|Z=0) = \frac{\mathbb P(Y=0,Z=0)}{\mathbb P(Z=0)}=\frac{\mathbb P(X=0,Z=0)}{\mathbb P(Z=0)}. $$

Comment: Thank you. And what is P(Y=0, Z=0)? What does that comma mean?

Comment: The probability that $Y=0$ and $Z=0$. It's shorthand for $\mathbb P(\{Y=0\}\cap\{Z=0\})$.